# HTML5 geolocation won't work in Firefox, Chrome and Chromium

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to use the HTML5 geolocation API; but I have problems to make it work on Firefox Chrome and Chromium :

```
init();

function init() {;
    // Get the current location
    getPosition();      
}

function getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail,{
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
        timeout:10000,
        maximumAge:Infinity
    });    
}   

function success(position) {
    alert("Your latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "longitude: "
        + position.coords.longitude);
}

function fail(e) {
    alert("Your position cannot be found"+e.code+" => "+e.message);
}
```

In IE9 and Safari it works flawlessly; but :

- in Firefox (v13 and V14) there is an error code 3 (timeout)
- in Chrome and Chromium (v20 and v21) there is and error code 2 with the message "Network location provider at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/browserlocation/json?browser=googlechrome&sensor=true' : Response was malformed."

I have a fresh install of Chrome (installed today on windows XP, no extensions) and I have authorized the geolocation in the browser.

You can try it there :
http://jsfiddle.net/mhj82/38/

Is there a solution to make it work on all browser supporting geolocation ?

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome v21 on Mac

Comment: I've asked some friends to test this jsfiddle, and it's seems to work for some of them, but that's not explaining why it doesn't work here :(

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?  I'm having the same issue... @Molochdaa

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this ?
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41001

At the end of the thread they come to the conclusion that in order to work in Chrome, geolocation must be performed on a device with a working wifi adapter.

Was wifi enabled on your computer ?

(dunno for firefox)

Comment: Yes, I've tested in Chrome on Mac OS X with a WiFi adapter, and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have to wait until the document is loaded to get it work in chrome

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) { 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tested in chrome desktop and mobile

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var latitude = null;
    var longitude = null;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   });



} else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser");
};
```